# How does django match MySQL datatypes?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am still new to Python Django and stumbled across something I don't understand.

First of all, a snippet from my model: (trimmed all others fields...)

```
class AircraftTypes(AbstractBaseModel):
    ...
    engines_count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default = 1)
    ...
```

Here a screenshot from MySQL Workbench created after the migration process.

[Screenshot_MySQL_Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAcXl.png)

I would have expected to see something link UNSIGNED TINYINT or so but why is Django creating a VARCHAR(1)?

Not surprisingly, when I try to enter a number like *103* it fails with MySQL error *"1406. Data too long for column"*.

Can someone enlighten me what is going on here, please?

By the way, I would not mind that much that numbers are stored as text since it will work but maybe not as efficient. But what I don't unterstand is where the limit to one character comes from. Is it my default value that is turning crazy?

Please help!!!

Florian

**EDIT**

Just tried some other combinations:

```
engines_count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
--> VARCHAR(1)

engines_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
--> INT(10)

engines_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
--> INT(10)
```

So I conclude, the default value isn't doing anything here (as expected...). But which point did I miss? Django docs say that PositiveSmallIntegerField can hold values from 0 to 32767 which definitely won't work with VARCHAR(1).

So still, what do I miss here?